# Dryer Drum Not Turning With Medium Sized Load

Tags: dryer

I replaced the idler tension pulley on my dryer, and upon re-assembly if I have a small load in the dryer the drum turns as expected.  If I have a medium sized load, the drum does not turn at all.  I have verified that the belt is turning, and the drum was spinning before I replaced the idler tension pulley, it just sounded like a squeaky wheel on a grocery cart.

What do I need to check to uncover why this issue is occurring?

Comment: Repair was botched, or belt was ruined by slipping in the past, or pulleys got slippery from rubber deposits from slipping in the past. Might need to replace belt AND clean off drive spindle of any contamination, burned rubber and the like.  I prefer to use a wire wheel for that, myself.

Comment: Your rollers (what the drum rolls on when the belt turns it) might also need replacement, and can be a source of squeaks themselves. I tend to get the "rollers/belt/tensioner kit" and store the old parts that don't appear to be totally dead for "next time" rather than getting the parts piecemeal (last one I did it was 10% more than just the parts I knew were bad, or less than half *.vs.* getting them all separately.)

Comment: @Ecnerwal - i've learned my lesson on that for sure.  I should have bought a kit that had all the parts (tension pulley, wheels and the belt) instead of buying the one piece that most of the initial sites I read from said it was.  If/when this happens again, DEF getting the all in one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably need a new belt.

If enough time has happen to wear out the pulley, probably enough time to stretch the belt beyond what the pulley can move to keep the belt tight enough.

If you get a new belt, will probably find it is a few inches shorter than the old belt.

Comment: i just did some further testing and it seems when I have a medium load in the drum the wheels/rollers on the back of the dryer that I place the drum on do not turn

Comment: They will need replacing also.  If not turning, they act like brakes for the drum.  The more weight the better they brake.  Imagine if you take the weight off of the wheels, they will flop around a bit, their bearing are going/gone.

Comment: that's what confuses me...they turn with nothing in the drum and/or a small load, but when the load gets more they do not turn

Comment: Yes, and belt can become glazed.

Comment: still think it's an issue with the belt even tho I can verify the belt is turning?

Comment: Age of machine important, but old enough to need new pulley and wheels, old enough to need a new belt.  Guessing about a ten year or older machine.

Comment: Model # WED9550WW1 - what belt do I need?

Comment: Google says 93 1/2 inch 4 rib, 3 groove.  Prices seem to be quite a range on a fast search.

Comment: Looks like this is turning into a shopping question... Did you check the stock level?

Comment: @crip659 - awesome!  Thanks for providing that.  Unfortunately for me my big box stores do not have that in stock within 50 miles of me...looks like amazon here I come :D

Comment: For my own sanity - let me ask this again...i can validate that the belt is spinning the drum is not, the wheels in the back of the dryer are not...still think it's the belt causing the issue?  Should I replace those two wheels also?

Comment: @user2676140 that would be when belt is slipping, add some regular soap on the underside of the belt

Comment: @Ruskes - thanks for the confirmation there.  I just couldn't make it make sense in my mind...altho i don't know much of anything about dryers :D

Comment: @user2676140 worn rubber belt, first start slipping. That can be avoided by adjusting the tension. Can you adjust it on your dryer ?

Comment: @Ruskes - how would I adjust it?  I may not have properly positioned the belt on the idler tension pulley when I replaced that...which could be leading to this giant headache

Comment: There is usually a tension adjustment well, on the outside of the belt, somewhere in the middle between motor and the drum.

Comment: @Ruskes - I'm not following you...the belt is very tight the entire way around the drum, around the pulley etc but I have no idea about a "tension adjustment well"

Comment: The motor pulley can also get glazed. "my big box stores do not have that in stock within 50 miles of me...looks like amazon here I come" just avoid at all costs any local, reputable, family-owned hardware or appliance stores or repair shops, because they might be knowledgeable and have exactly what you need. Those businesses must be crushed!  For some reason.  Go to Amazon, ever the fount of quality and non-scammy items.

Comment: @user2676140 how did you test the tension ? How far can you twist the belt, it should not twist at all.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica - I got it from `partselect.com` i've bought off here multiple times before and no issues

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the belt tension or replace parts.

Source:[pulley](https://www.appliancepartspros.com/repair-help/whirlpool-dryer-wed9550ww1-repair/wed9550ww1-noisy.html)

The idler pulley is responsible for maintaining tension on the drive belt so that the drum spins correctly when operating. Normal wear and tear combined with consistent heat from daily use may cause the idler pulley to crack and break. If the idler pulley does not have the proper tension on the belt, the dryer will not operate efficiently. It may not dry clothes entirely or may not operate at all. If the idler pulley is not working correctly, it will need to be replaced.A Phillips screwdriver, nut driver, putty knife, flathead screwdriver, and needle nose pliers are needed for this repair. The idler pulley is located on the drum of the dryer. Before beginning, make sure the dryer is disconnected from the power source. Remove the back panel on the dryer to access the drum. Pull the drum and replace the part. Put the drum back in place and reinstall the cover and reconnect the power. Start the dryer to test the repair.This idler pulley is a plastic and rubber part.

**The tension adjustment:**

The correct tension is achieved when you can not twist the belt more than 1/8-1/4 of inch.

Comment: Not sure why you included an explanation of the idler pulley. OP already replaced that.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact because the OP did not adjust the tension correctly.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact also learning from your posts

Comment: huh, seems a WHOLE lot easier to replace this by removing the back panel!  The video I watched had me removing the entire front of the washer as well as the drum

Comment: I've ordered a new belt and ordered 4 new "wheels" that help spin the drum.  Just looking at the belt, I did notice some cracking/fraying in the belt so probably a good time to replace that anyway.

Comment: @user2676140 my instruction agree with you, access from back.